# Getting the Hazelcast map size in MB or KB via jmx monitoring

Tags: size, monitoring, jmx, hazelcast

I am monitoring HazelCast 2.6.9 via JMX. I am trying to extract the size of each and every map using cmdline-jmxclient-0.10.3.jar available at http://crawler.archive.org/cmdline-jmxclient/downloads.html ( documentation at : http://crawler.archive.org/cmdline-jmxclient/index.html). I am able to get the size of each map as in number of records present in the map using the following command:

java -jar /home/impadmin/Desktop/test/cmdline-jmxclient-0.10.3.jar - 127.0.0.1:8282 com.hazelcast:Cluster=_hzInstance,name=Users,type=Map Size

I am trying to retrieve the size of map as in KB's and MB's. I did search on net about it but couldn't find a way to extract the map size in KB's or MB's. Please help. Any other options to retrieve the size in KB's are also appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this applies to Hazelcast 2.6.9, so apologies if not...

Have you looked at the localOwnedEntryMemoryCost attribute?  I believe that gives the Map size for the given node in bytes.  You would have to collate this value from each of your nodes in order to get the total Map size for the cluster.

The Enterprise version Hazelcast JMX API may have more options for getting this information at the cluster level, but I've not used it myself.